# Fatal error encountered during command execution - Only in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-5.5

I am having trouble with running this query. On my personal computer I had upgraded MySQL to 5.7 to do some better logging and this query works just fine. When I put it into production on 5.5 it works, but only sometimes.

Using HeidiSQL in production (i7 3.4GHz - 16GB ram) it works but takes 50 seconds to run , but on my  Dual 6-core 64GB ram it only takes 2.6 seconds on my PC using the same data). Using my C# app, I get an error "Fatal error encountered during command execution". Any idea what is different about those two situations that it would work in one but not the other? Does the execution time have any bearing on it?

I am using the same c# query execution method for 20 other queries that all work just fine, but for some reason this one is having trouble.

Query:

```
SELECT p.patnum            AS reference_id, 
       p.guarantor         AS guarantor_reference_id, 
       p.bal_0_30          AS balance_0_30, 
       p.bal_31_60         AS balance_31_60, 
       p.bal_61_90         AS balance_61_90, 
       p.balover90         AS balance_over_90, 
       p.baltotal          AS account_balance, 
       pending_writeoff, 
       claims_estimated_amount, 
       patient_portion_due AS amount_due_from_patient, 
       Sum(procfee)        AS lifetime_value 
FROM   patient AS p 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT patient.patnum, 
                         patient.guarantor, 
                         patient.bal_0_30, 
                         patient.bal_31_60, 
                         patient.bal_61_90, 
                         patient.balover90, 
                         guarAging.baltotal, 
                         guarAging.inswoest 
                                             AS 
                                                       pending_writeoff, 
                         guarAging.inspayest 
                                             AS 
                                                       claims_estimated_amount, 
                         guarAging.baltotal - guarAging.inspayest - 
                         guarAging.inswoest 
                                             AS 
                         patient_portion_due 
                  FROM   (SELECT tSums.patnum, 
                                 Round(CASE 
                                         WHEN tSums.totalcredits >= 
                                              tSums.chargesover90 
                                       THEN 0 
                                         ELSE tSums.chargesover90 - 
                                              tSums.totalcredits 
                                       end, 2)              Balover90, 
                                 Round(CASE 
                                         WHEN tSums.totalcredits <= 
                                              tSums.chargesover90 
                                       THEN 
                                         tSums.charges_61_90 
                                         WHEN tSums.chargesover90 + 
                                              tSums.charges_61_90 
                                              <= 
                                              tSums.totalcredits 
                                       THEN 0 
                                         ELSE tSums.chargesover90 + 
                                              tSums.charges_61_90 
                                              - 
                                              tSums.totalcredits 
                                       end, 2)              Bal_61_90, 
                                 Round(CASE 
                                         WHEN tSums.totalcredits < 
                                              tSums.chargesover90 + 
                                              tSums.charges_61_90 THEN 
                                         tSums.charges_31_60 
                                         WHEN tSums.chargesover90 + 
                                              tSums.charges_61_90 
                                              + tSums.charges_31_60 <= 
                                              tSums.totalcredits THEN 0 
                                         ELSE tSums.chargesover90 + 
                                              tSums.charges_61_90 
                                              + tSums.charges_31_60 - 
                                              tSums.totalcredits 
                                       end, 2)              Bal_31_60, 
                                 Round(CASE 
                                         WHEN tSums.totalcredits < 
                                              tSums.chargesover90 + 
                                              tSums.charges_61_90 
                                              + tSums.charges_31_60 THEN 
                                         tSums.charges_0_30 
                                         WHEN tSums.chargesover90 + 
                                              tSums.charges_61_90 
                                              + tSums.charges_31_60 + 
                                              tSums.charges_0_30 <= 
                                              tSums.totalcredits 
                                       THEN 0 
                                         ELSE tSums.chargesover90 + 
                                              tSums.charges_61_90 
                                              + tSums.charges_31_60 + 
                                              tSums.charges_0_30 - 
                                              tSums.totalcredits 
                                       end, 2)              Bal_0_30, 
                                 Round(tSums.baltotal, 2)   BalTotal, 
                                 Round(tSums.inswoest, 2)   InsWoEst, 
                                 Round(tSums.inspayest, 2)  InsPayEst, 
                                 Round(tSums.payplandue, 2) PayPlanDue 
                          FROM   (SELECT p.guarantor              PatNum, 
                                         Sum(CASE 
                                               WHEN trans.tranamount > 0 
                                                    AND trans.trandate < 
                                                        '2018-01-11' 
                                             THEN 
                                               trans.tranamount 
                                               ELSE 0 
                                             end)                 ChargesOver90, 
                                         Sum(CASE 
                                               WHEN trans.tranamount > 0 
                                                    AND trans.trandate < 
                                                        '2018-01-12' 
                                                    AND trans.trandate >= 
                                                        '2018-02-10' 
                                             THEN 
                                               trans.tranamount 
                                               ELSE 0 
                                             end)                 Charges_61_90, 
                                         Sum(CASE 
                                               WHEN trans.tranamount > 0 
                                                    AND trans.trandate < 
                                                        '2018-02-11' 
                                                    AND trans.trandate >= 
                                                        '2018-03-12' 
                                             THEN 
                                               trans.tranamount 
                                               ELSE 0 
                                             end)                 Charges_31_60, 
                                         Sum(CASE 
                                               WHEN trans.tranamount > 0 
                                                    AND trans.trandate <= 
                                                        '2018-03-13' 
                                                    AND trans.trandate >= 
                                                        '2018-04-12' 
                                             THEN 
                                               trans.tranamount 
                                               ELSE 0 
                                             end)                 Charges_0_30, 
                                         -Sum(CASE 
                                                WHEN trans.tranamount < 0 
                                                     AND trans.trandate <= 
                                                         '2018-04-12' 
                                              THEN 
                                                trans.tranamount 
                                                ELSE 0 
                                              end)                TotalCredits, 
                                         Sum(CASE 
                                               WHEN trans.tranamount != 0 THEN 
                                               trans.tranamount 
                                               ELSE 0 
                                             end)                 BalTotal, 
                                         Sum(trans.inswoest)      InsWoEst, 
                                         Sum(trans.inspayest)     InsPayEst, 
                                         Sum(trans.payplanamount) PayPlanDue 
                                  FROM   (SELECT 'Proc' 
                                                 TranType, 
                                                 pl.patnum, 
                                                 pl.procdate 
                                                 TranDate, 
                                                 pl.procfee * ( 
                                                 pl.unitqty + pl.baseunits ) 
                                                 TranAmount, 
                                                 0 
                                                 PayPlanAmount 
                                                 , 
                                                 0 
                                                 InsWoEst, 
                                                 0 
                                                 InsPayEst 
                                          FROM   procedurelog pl 
                                          WHERE  pl.procstatus = 2 
                                                 AND pl.procfee != 0 
                                          UNION ALL 
                                          SELECT 'Claimproc' TranType, 
                                                 cp.patnum, 
                                                 cp.datecp   TranDate, 
                                                 ( CASE 
                                                     WHEN cp. status != 0 THEN 
                                                     ( CASE 
                                                     WHEN cp.payplannum = 0 THEN 
                                                     - 
                                                     cp.inspayamt 
                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                       end ) 
                                                     - 
                                                     cp.writeoff 
                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                   end )     TranAmount, 
                                                 ( CASE 
                                                     WHEN cp.payplannum != 0 
                                                          AND cp. status IN ( 1, 
                                                              4, 5 ) 
                                                   THEN - 
                                                     cp.inspayamt 
                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                   end )     PayPlanAmount, 
                                                 ( CASE 
                                                     WHEN cp. status = 0 THEN 
                                                     cp.writeoff 
                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                   end )     InsWoEst, 
                                                 ( CASE 
                                                     WHEN cp. status = 0 THEN 
                                                     cp.inspayest 
                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                   end )     InsPayEst 
                                          FROM   claimproc cp 
                                          WHERE  cp. status IN ( 0, 1, 4, 5, 7 ) 
                                          HAVING tranamount != 0 
                                                  OR payplanamount != 0 
                                                  OR inswoest != 0 
                                                  OR inspayest != 0 
                                          UNION ALL 
                                          SELECT 'Adj'     TranType, 
                                                 a.patnum, 
                                                 a.adjdate TranDate, 
                                                 a.adjamt  TranAmount, 
                                                 0         PayPlanAmount, 
                                                 0         InsWoEst, 
                                                 0         InsPayEst 
                                          FROM   adjustment a 
                                          WHERE  a.adjamt != 0 
                                          UNION ALL 
                                          SELECT 'PatPay'   TranType, 
                                                 ps.patnum, 
                                                 ps.datepay TranDate, 
                                                 ( CASE 
                                                     WHEN ps.payplannum = 0 THEN 
                                                     - 
                                                     ps.splitamt 
                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                   end )    TranAmount, 
                                                 ( CASE 
                                                     WHEN ps.payplannum != 0 
                                                   THEN - 
                                                     ps.splitamt 
                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                   end )    PayPlanAmount, 
                                                 0          InsWoEst, 
                                                 0          InsPayEst 
                                          FROM   paysplit ps 
                                          WHERE  ps.splitamt != 0 
                                          UNION ALL 
                                          SELECT 'PPCharge' 
                                                 TranType, 
                                                 ppc.guarantor 
                                                 PatNum, 
                                                 ppc.chargedate 
                                                 TranDate, 
                                                 0 
                                                 TranAmount, 
                                                 Coalesce (ppc.principal + 
                                                 ppc.interest, 0) 
                                                 PayPlanAmount 
                                                 , 
                                                 0 
                                                 InsWoEst, 
                                                 0 
                                                 InsPayEst 
                                          FROM   payplancharge ppc 
                                          WHERE  ppc.chargedate <= '2018-04-22' 
                                                 AND ppc.chargetype = 0 
                                                 AND Coalesce (ppc.principal + 
                                                               ppc.interest, 0) 
                                                     != 0 
                                          UNION ALL 
                                          SELECT 'PPComplete'     TranType, 
                                                 pp.patnum, 
                                                 pp.payplandate   TranDate, 
                                                 -pp.completedamt TranAmount, 
                                                 0                PayPlanAmount, 
                                                 0                InsWoEst, 
                                                 0                InsPayEst 
                                          FROM   payplan pp 
                                          WHERE  pp.completedamt != 0) trans 
                                         RIGHT JOIN patient p 
                                                 ON p.patnum = trans.patnum 
                                  GROUP  BY p.guarantor 
                                  ORDER  BY NULL) tSums) guarAging 
                         INNER JOIN patient 
                                 ON patient.patnum = guarAging.patnum 
                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT patnum, 
                                           claimstatus, 
                                           claimfee, 
                                           inspayest, 
                                           writeoff 
                                    FROM   claim) AS c 
                                ON c.patnum = patient.patnum 
                  GROUP  BY patient.patnum) AS results 
              ON results.patnum = p.patnum 
       LEFT JOIN procedurelog AS plog 
              ON plog.patnum = p.patnum 
                 AND plog.procstatus = 2 
GROUP  BY p.patnum
```

C# Execution:

```
   try
    {
        using (var mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString))
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();

            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, mySqlConnection))
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())   <= FAILS HERE
                {
```

For what it is worth, at one point I did see the error "fatal error during data read" and  added this, but the other error is still happening:

```
MySqlCommand timeoutAdjust = new MySqlCommand("set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999", mySqlConnection); // Setting tiimeout on mysqlServer
                    timeoutAdjust.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Is there a method to get the MySQL error message and display that?

Comment: sounds like a memory issue. How much ram can mysql use in production? how much can it use on your development PC?

Comment: Thats one big SQL query.

Comment: Try to set `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;` -> 0 is infinity

Comment: Thank you so much Rand, setting `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;` worked. It must have taken longer when executing from within my app than within the HeidiSQL app.   Luksch - the app only was using about 85MB of ram, the mysqld service was using about 35MB.

Comment: i recommend you check some of the conditions, e.g. for  Charges_61_90,  we see `trandate < '2018-01-12' AND trandate >=  '2018-02-10' ` ... we know there are no values of trandate that are going to satisfy that condition. (We might better just write `SUM(0)` and get rid of the CASE expression.) Same for  Charges_31_60.